# Ruby On Rails - What do these Brakeman warnings mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, brakeman

I am using `brakeman` `gem` for scanning my app.

After scanning the app, I get the following warnings:

```
#Security warnings

Method                  | Warning Type    | Message                    
------------------------------------------------------
show                    | Unscoped Find   | Unscoped call to PatientMessage#find near line 27: Message.find(+params[:id]+)
------------------------------------------------------

#Controller warnings:

Controller            | Warning Type               | Message
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
ApplicationController | Cross-Site Request Forgery | 'protect_from_forgery' should be called in ApplicationController
```

Can someone help figure out what these warnings mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The protect_from_forgery error is pretty much self-explanatory, (it's telling you to include the method that helps to protect your site from cross-site scripting in your application controller) but the docs for the Unscoped Find are here: http://brakemanscanner.org/docs/warning_types/unscoped_find/

Basically, it's telling you that you should do something like:

```
current_user.messages.find(params[:id])
```

instead of Message.find so users can't just find any message by passing an id into params. The example above assumes that you have a current_user helper, and that a message belongs to a user, which may not be the case in your app, but that's what the warning means.

Comment: Following the documentation, I've added the following code: `protect_from_forgery :with => :exception` to solve the `'protect_from_forgery' should be called in ApplicationController` warning. But, this broke my devise authentication service.