# What is this "Unscoped call to" warning in Brakeman?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, brakeman

I am getting a warning message when I scan my code with Brakeman's Tool. It states that there is an **Unscoped call to** the following query:

```
@applicant = Applicant.find(params[:id])
```

Here is the actual error message:

```
+------------+----------------------+---------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Confidence | Class                | Method  | Warning Type  | Message                                                                                                                                 |
+------------+----------------------+---------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Weak       | ApplicantsController | show    | Unscoped Find | Unscoped call to Applicant#find near line 25: Applicant.find(+params[:id]+)                                                             |                                                       |
+------------+----------------------+---------+---------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But when I replace the above query with the following one then it's fine:

```
@applicant = Applicant.where("id = ?", params[:id]).first
```

I don't understand what's wrong with the first query.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Brakeman is just warning you that you're querying the entire Applicant table, and not scoping it under another model, like `current_tenant.applicants.find...`. From [Brakeman's docs](http://brakemanscanner.org/docs/warning_types/unscoped_find/):

> Unscoped find (and related methods) are a form of Direct Object Reference. Models which belong to another model should typically be accessed via a scoped query.
>
> For example, if an Account belongs to a User, then this may be an unsafe unscoped find:
>
> ```
> Account.find(params[:id])
> ```
>
> Depending on the action, this could allow an attacker to access any account they wish.
>
> Instead, it should be scoped to the currently logged-in user:
>
> ```
> current_user = User.find(session[:user_id])
> current_user.accounts.find(params[:id])
> ```

If this is your desired behavior, you can configure Brakeman to ignore this warning as a false positive. To do that, run `brakeman` with the `-I` flag (or `--interactive-ignore`). Follow the instructions on [Ignoring False Positives](http://brakemanscanner.org/docs/ignoring_false_positives/) to step through all the warnings, and add this particular one to your ignore file.

In a nutshell:

```
$ brakeman -I
Input file: |config/brakeman.ignore| 
# press Enter to accept the default ignore file
No such file. Continue with empty config? 
# press Enter to create the file
> 
1. Inspect all warnings
2. Hide previously ignored warnings
3. Skip - use current ignore configuration
# press 2 to step through all warnings, skipping previously ignored 
# Brakeman will now step through each warning, prompting you to for each one. 
# Press i to add this warning to the ignore list. 
# When finished, Brakeman will ask you what to do. 
# Press 1 to save changes to the ignore file.
```

The next time you run Brakeman, this warning should not appear.

Comment: thanks so much for this info, is the way which i am trying to use in my second query is correct?

Comment: I would use the first query (`@applicant = Applicant.find(params[:id])`) - doing it the second way (`where..first`) will not raise a 404 error if the record is not found. Doing it the first way will raise an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound exception, which is what you want.

Comment: Here's a similar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32102172/ruby-on-rails-what-do-these-brakeman-warnings-mean

Comment: I was just reading the Brakeman docs, and found out that you can configure it to ignore this warning as a false positive so it doesn't keep bugging you: http://brakemanscanner.org/docs/ignoring_false_positives/